# Where would I install a bonding screw in this panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Im trying to help my grand father and believe I need a bonding screw installed. (he has neutrals and grounds on the same bar)

Can anyone please indicate where it goes on the main panel?

If you could highlight the location on my attached picture, that would be much appreciated.

Thank you![image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?  What are the symptoms?

Comment: I believe the bonding screw is missing from this panel. I would like to know the exact location on the panel for the bonding screw.

Comment: Is this a Main or a Sub panel? If it is a Sub, you don't bond.
Sq. D.'s instructions just say to install the bonding screw through the hole in the Neutral bar. I see a hole on the upper right. The details were probably on the card that was attached to the bonding screw.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=40&v=6HGaRNBcADY

Comment: Is this a subpanel?  It looks awfully, awfully light to be a main panel.

Comment: What I'm getting at is people don't normally open up a panel if there is no problem, and not having a bonding screw doesn't normally cause a problem - its a safety issue.  Just trying to make sure you are fixing the right thing.

Comment: Yes, [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/338621) may be a meta-issue.  The more you can tell us about what you're chasing, the more we can help.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I really do appreciate it. Yes, this is a smaller/older home. This is the main panel. I bought this property for my grandpa and per the report it stated that the neutral and grounds can not be on the same lugs (which  I corrrected) In addition, I did some checking online and was advised that a bonding screw needs to be installed if the neutrals and grounds are on the same bar. Im making sure the home is safe. Thank you

Comment: @Joe -- can you post a photo of the label on the inside of one side of the loadcenter box (cabinet)?

Comment: Sure! I can do that now

Comment: In the main panel the grounds and neutrals can be on the same buss, it looks like there is a bonding screw there. I would complain about that inspector not knowing code if this is the true main panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You should be good to go already

According to the diagram on the labels inside the cabinet proper, the furthest-right screw position on the neutral intertie bar is where the bonding screw goes, and it appears to be already populated in your photos, as it should be.

Comment: My only question would be is this a main panel or a sub-panel? If its a main the bond is ok. If it is a sub then you will need to install a ground bus and terminate grounds there.

Comment: Thank you. Just to finalize the answer,  is the bonding screw already installed?  I added another photo with red and green arrows. Can you please confirm with arrow is the location of the bonding screw. Thanks again

Comment: @RetiredMasterElectrician -- it is a main panel as per the OP's comment on their question.

Comment: @Joe -- it is indeed.